Is there any way to embed a form created with FormBuilder in WordPress?
I have created form using AFform form builder extension in Civi CRM, not able to use on any pages in WordPress, basically it will not have option to embedded form. can any one please help me to achieve this, basically embedded(shortcode) form should be use on any pages.

You can use shortcodes to embed afforms in a WordPress post or page
[civicrm component="afform" name="afformQuickAddOrganization"]

where afformQuickAddOrganization is the name of the form name which you should be able to see on form builder list page


Thank you @Pradeep Nayak, will give it try
